# How to make set of mat-card containing different charts have drag and drop feature and auto align

Tags: drag-and-drop, draggable, angular13, angular-cdk-drag-drop

**HTML**

```
<div class="boundary">
        <div cdkDrag fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="15px" cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal" cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" [cdkDropData]="list">
            <div *ngFor="let li of list" [cdkDragData]="li" cdkDrag cdkDragBoundary=".boundary">
                <div cdkDragBoundary=".boundary" class="mt_15"  *ngIf="li == 1">
                    <mat-card matBadge="2" matBadgeColor="warn" matBadgeOverlap="true">
                        <div style="display: block">
                            <canvas baseChart [data]="pieChartData0" [labels]="pieChartLabels" [chartType]="pieChartType"
                                [options]="pieChartOptions" [colors]="pieChartColors"></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </mat-card>
                </div>
                <div cdkDragBoundary=".boundary" class="mt_15"  *ngIf="li == 2">
                    <mat-card>
                        <div style="display: block">
                            <canvas baseChart [data]="pieChartData1" [labels]="pieChartLabels" [chartType]="pieChartType"
                                [options]="pieChartOptions" [colors]="pieChartColors"></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </mat-card>
                </div>
                <div cdkDragBoundary=".boundary" class="mt_15"  *ngIf="li == 3">
                    <mat-card matBadge="1" matBadgeColor="warn" matBadgeOverlap="true">
                        <div style="display: block">
                            <canvas baseChart [data]="pieChartData2" [labels]="pieChartLabels" [chartType]="pieChartType"
                                [options]="pieChartOptions" [colors]="pieChartColors"></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </mat-card>
                </div>
                <div cdkDragBoundary=".boundary" class="mt_15"  *ngIf="li == 4">
                    <mat-card>
                        <div style="display: block">
                            <canvas baseChart [data]="pieChartData3" [labels]="pieChartLabels" [chartType]="pieChartType"
                                [options]="pieChartOptions" [colors]="pieChartColors"></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </mat-card>
                </div>
                <div cdkDragBoundary=".boundary" class="mt_15"  *ngIf="li == 5">
                    <mat-card>
                        <div style="display: block">
                            <canvas baseChart [data]="pieChartData4" [labels]="pieChartLabels" [chartType]="pieChartType"
                                [options]="pieChartOptions" [colors]="pieChartColors"></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </mat-card>
                </div>
                <div cdkDragBoundary=".boundary" class="mt_15"  *ngIf="li == 6">
                    <mat-card>
                        <div style="display: block">
                            <canvas baseChart [data]="pieChartData4" [labels]="pieChartLabels" [chartType]="pieChartType"
                                [options]="pieChartOptions" [colors]="pieChartColors"></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </mat-card>
                </div>
                <div cdkDragBoundary=".boundary" class="mt_15"  *ngIf="li == 7">
                    <mat-card>
                        <div style="display: block">
                            <canvas baseChart [data]="pieChartData4" [labels]="pieChartLabels" [chartType]="pieChartType"
                                [options]="pieChartOptions" [colors]="pieChartColors"></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </mat-card>
                </div>
                <div cdkDragBoundary=".boundary" class="mt_15"  *ngIf="li == 8">
                    <mat-card>
                        <div style="display: block">
                            <canvas baseChart [data]="pieChartData4" [labels]="pieChartLabels" [chartType]="pieChartType"
                                [options]="pieChartOptions" [colors]="pieChartColors"></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </mat-card>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartType, ChartOptions, Chart } from 'chart.js';
import { Label } from 'ng2-charts';

@Component({
selector: 'app-dashboard',
templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
 list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
 pieChartOptions: ChartOptions;
 pieChartLabels: Label[];
 pieChartData0: number[];
 pieChartData1: number[];
 pieChartData2: number[];
 pieChartData3: number[];
 pieChartData4: number[];
 pieChartType: ChartType;
 pieChartLegend: boolean;
 pieChartPlugins = [];
 pieChartColors = []

 constructor(  ) {    }
 ngOnInit(): void {
    Chart.plugins.register
    this.pieChartOptions = this.createOptions()
    this.pieChartLabels = ['Abnormal', 'Warning', 'No Abnormality'];
    this.pieChartData0 = [2, 0, 8];
    this.pieChartData1 = [0, 0, 10];
    this.pieChartData2 = [2, 5, 3];
    this.pieChartData3 = [2, 0, 8];
    this.pieChartData4 = [0, 0, 10];
    this.pieChartType = 'pie';
    // this.pieChartPlugins = [pluginLabels];
    // this.pieChartLegend = true
    this.pieChartColors = [
        {
            backgroundColor: ['orange', 'darkorange', 'lightblue'],
        }
    ];
 }
 private createOptions(): ChartOptions {
    return {
        responsive: true,
        // maintainAspectRatio: false,
        legend: {
            display: false,
            labels: {
                padding: 10,
                boxWidth: 13,
            },
            position: 'bottom',
        },
        plugins: {
            labels: {
                render: 'value',
                fontSize: 16,
                position: 'center',
                fontStyle: '500',
                fontFamily: "'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', 'sans-serif'",
                precision: 2
            },
        }
    }
 }

 drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(this.list, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
 }
}
```

I'm able to achieve drag and drop but auto alignment is not working based on the id for each **div**.

I took the reference from the following link [Drag-Drop](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview)

Using the reference it's achieavable to just drag anywhere, but as I want it should be within certain space for which I used class i.e **boundary**.

Also since I'm not able to get the card as dynamic so I'm using ***ngIf** contion.

If anyone have any suggestion or reference that would be of much help.